# How do I replace the name of an image with its classification? The classification are in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, dataset, classification

I'm doing a pre-processing of data to use on a neural network, and I have some photos saved in a folder, which are named by a number (1.png, 2.png, 3.png). Also, I have a csv that contains the classification of each image in the folder. The structure of the csv file is as follows:

filename;class

Example:

```
1.png;cat
2.png;dog
3.png;cat
```

What I am trying to do is, using csv, replace the name of the photo with its classification + its name.

In the end, the result of the names of each image would be: cat_1.png, dog_2.png, cat_3.png.

I'm using python 3 and jupyter for development.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

csv= pd.read_csv('path_to.csv')

path_to_imgs = os.path.join('path','to','img')

def rename_files(row):
    column_class = row['column of class in csv']
    file_name = row['column of file name in csv']
    new_file_name = f'{column_class}_{file_name}'
    os.rename(
        os.path.join(path_to_imgs, file_name),
        os.path.join(path_to_imgs, new_file_name)
    )

csv.apply(rename_files, axis=1)
```

read the csv files, create a function (`rename_files`) that goes row by row on the csv file changing the old name in the csv (`file_name`) to the new format (`new_file_name`).

Comment: With a few minor adjustments your code worked for me! Only syntax adjustments: "def" instead of "function" and change "class" to another name, because it is a reserved word. Thank you!

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira hahaha I don't know why I typed those things hahaha i'll edit the answer :)